# Get specific textline in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, multiple-columns

currently i am trying to work with text displayed in cols on a webpage. 
In fact i am trying to simulate `CSS3 Multiple Columns`.

I start with one column that contains all the text, use `Hyphenator.js` to improve the text quality and after that i want to split at the first invisible line and add the text to a new floating div. I want to do this until i have no undisplayed text left.

The problem i am facing is, that the layout is fluid and i have no idea, how i can get a specific line of the text.

I started by extracting the css attribute `line-height`, the `height` of the parent div that uses `overflow: hidden;` to hide longer text and the `height` of the text-div. But now i am stuck, because i know no way to determine how many words are on one line.

I tried also to use regexp to split the text in sentences. And add one after another until the height of the div is to big for the surrounding one. But with this i don't have the benefit of `Hyphenator.js`.

This is an excerpt from my html:

```
<div class="col col_2">
    <div class="col_content">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <div class="text">
            <div class="start_col hyphenate">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `start_col` will be hidden after the process is done, to use the original text if the user resizes the window.

This is the regexp i use to split the text into sentences:

```
var sentences = $(this).text().replace(/\.+/g,'.|').replace(/\?/g,'?|').replace(/\!/g,'!|').split("|");
var temp = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++)
{
    var sentence = $.trim(sentences[i]);
    if(sentence !== "")
        temp.push(sentence);
    sentences = temp;
}
```

But like i wrote before, with this i cannot benefit from `Hyphenator.js`.

I will be happy explaining more if i was unclear in some point.

Comment: I've read somewhere you could wrap every word in a `span` and then start adding their widths untill the next span would exceed the width of the container. That is one line of text. Don't know if it helps much, though.

Comment: @JakubMichálek: Thx for the tip. I will look into it. But it sounds like i have to do some complex calculations and i am not quite sure what happens if all text cols where recalculated after resize.

Comment: @Tobias Kun: Sorry, but don't try to do the browser's job. Concentrate on writing semantically correct HTML markup. Your text isn't even wrapped in 'P' elements. And actually more and more browsers supprt the CSS [hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) property.

Comment: One more tip to simplify calculation would be to start by dividing the text by the number of columns, then checking how much off you are and finally shifting words (or spans) back and forth till you're happy. But I personally think this is a good example of downgrading - modern browsers know css columns and hyphens, old browsers just get a one column text.

Comment: @Netsurfer: Sure modern browsers know `hyphens` and are able to display content in multiple columns but i need to simulate it in older browsers. And downgrading should not be showing them one single column, because it would destroy the `newspaper` layout. I have a max-height a column can have and have to split it there. Sometimes only 2 columns are visible and the text is shortened with `...`. And in the detail view i have larger columns where all are visible. I am searching for a possibility to simulate it in older browsers.

Comment: Why don't you just use an existing solution?

Comment: @JakubMichálek: I do not know any. If you know one please tell me :)

Comment: for jQuery: https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin, https://code.google.com/p/js-columns/ maybe you can find some for pure JS as well

Comment: @Tobias Kun: So we are talking about "progressive enhancement" vs. "graceful degradation"!? From my point of view users that use an outdated browser might have a reason for doing so. It is not the job of an author to bring all the latest functionality to their old browsers. How many older sites you know using a "newspaper (multi-column) layout"? There is a reason for it, because without the browser supporting the needed CSS features for this, you cannot accomplish this, at least not in a satisfying way. BTW: Which "older" browsers do you want to support?

Comment: @Netsurfer: I am a pro "progressive enhancement" guy. But if i want to sell software to customers like news pages, it would be better to include most visitors of their site. This could be people that surf at work and have older IE-Versions that were patched until they were secure or others that simply do not want to upgrade. If i as a developer build this system a better downgrading would be a unique selling point. I sure want to use the new technologies, but want to increase the user experience in older browsers too. (for example IE7+)

Comment: @Tobias Kun: OK, things become a little clearer ...! ;-) But the fact still remains that **there is no way to achieve this at affordable costs!** See also [**Using CSS multi-column layouts**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts). And as a professional you should be able to decide when it makes sense and when not. IMHO in this case it does absolutely not! And even when you'll find a JS solution, what if JS is deactivated/ disabled? With every step forward you are going two steps back, because you constantly create new problems. ;-)

Comment: @Tobias Kun: Good luck! I will keep an eye on this question, so please let us know if you found a solution - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but let me take a stab at it anyway.

Why not use strlen() http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strlen.asp and outerWidth() in jQuery to work out a close approximation of how many characters on each line, rather than how many words.

character width would be equal to font-size (or something)
so amount of characters on each line is equal to the character width divided by the outerWidth of the div. Hope this make sense.

Comment: I have text that is optimized with `Hyphenator.js`, which means longer words will be split at one syllable to allow more text on one line. Using the string length could be a possible way, but it cannot be precise enough. I want to build a webapplication that looks alot like a newspaper and text that was split at the wrong position could belittle the user experience.

Comment: @Daniel Schwarz: No, it does not. The entire plan makes no sense! In your proposal you would have to take the actual font, font-size, letter-spacing, word-spacing etc. into account. It is totally absurd to make the job of the browser ...! Write semantically correct HTML markup and style it with CSS - that's it.

Comment: @Netsurfer is right. I can't think of a better way, though. Rewrite your HTML5 and consider other options for layouts? Have you tried masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/ - they have many different options for multi-column layouts and work well with other scripts.